# The exponential function and one-parameter subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation, matrix-exponential

In Geometrical Methods for Mathematical Physics, Schutz speaks of a left-invariant vector field $\bar{V}$ at the identity $e$ of a Lie group $G$.  He writes:

> Unlike an arbitrary vector field, $\bar{V}$ is determined completely by $\bar{V}_e$, so we can denote the points of $G$ on this curve by $$g_{\bar{V}_e}(t)=\exp(t\bar{V}_e).$$  Because exponentiation has, by definition, the property $$\exp(t_2\bar{V})\exp(t_1\bar{V})|_e=\exp\left[(t_1+t_2)\bar{V}\right]|_e,$$ the points on these integral curves form a group ...

It is my understanding, however, that exponentiation does not necessarily have the sum-to-product property when dealing with vectors/matrices.  What is the deeper reason behind Schutz making this claim?

Comment: If I understand you the "sum-to-product" property you mean when does $e^{\mathbf{X}}e^{\mathbf{Y}} = e^{\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{Y}}$, well it happens when $[\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}] = 0$, and look at $[a\mathbf{X}, b\mathbf{X}]$ for scalars $a,b$.

Comment: @Nadiels Correct.  Please expand this and submit as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is true that $\exp(X)\exp(Y)$ in general is not
$\exp(X+Y)$. In fact you have a very well known formula that is the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Formula that states 
$$\exp\left(X\right)\exp\left(Y\right)=\exp\left(X+Y+\frac{1}{2}\left[X,Y\right]+\frac{1}{12}\left(\left[X,\left[X,Y\right]\right]+\left[Y,\left[Y,X\right]\right]\right)...\right)$$
As you can see since the brackets are linear and $\left[X,X\right]=0 $you have
$$\exp\left(t_1X\right)\exp\left(t_2X\right)=\exp\left(t_1X+t_2X+\frac{t_1t_2}{2}\left[X,X\right]+...\right)=\exp\left(t_1X+t_2X\right)$$
Another way of seeing the same thing in this particular case is just writing the series of the exponential and grouping $t_1,t_2$.